# How to Move from outlook 2011 to outlook 2007?

Tags: ms-office

I want to move from outlook 2011 to outlook 2007 but can't create pst from my mac pc. What should I do now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all know its not possible to import olm files of outlook 2011 to outlook 2007 as outlook 2007 is not compatible with olm format but supports pst file formats easily. So you need to first get your files from olm format to pst file format & for that You can check for your solution to move from one platform to another platofrm : http://www.office.mvps.org/cross_platform/mac_win.html there are some solutions offered to users.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Link-only answers may get deleted.

Comment: i have shared some more knowledge about the same..

Comment: thanks Danie for your guidance to move mails from outlook 2011 to outlook 2007, visited your link & got solution from your link as Outlook mac exporter for converting olm to pst. Successfully converted files & now accessing it in Outlook 2007 after importing pst.